# rigid type variable error in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Why this gives `rigid type variable` error:

```
data MyTree a  = Leaf [a]
               | Branch (String, a) [MyTree a] 
               deriving (Show)


list :: MyTree a -> [a]
list (Leaf [])                = []
list (Leaf m)                 = m
list (Branch _ (x:xs))        = list x ++ map (list) xs

-------------------------------------------------------------
Couldn't match type `a' with `[a]'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for list :: MyTree a -> [a]
          at test.hs:6:15
    Expected type: MyTree a -> a
      Actual type: MyTree a -> [a]
    In the first argument of `map', namely `(list)'
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely `map (list) xs'
    In the expression: list x ++ map (list) xs
```

Comment: hmm, you also have another mistake in the code with `list (Node _ (x:xs))` as you haven't defined Node as a value constructor for the type MyTree, i.e. you only provided Leaf and Branch

Comment: Hmm, code is still broken as what is an `IndexedTree`? You never defined that in this code snippet.

Comment: Code is still broken because your `Branch` value constructor takes two arguments, but in your pattern match you're only giving one to `Branch_` (which should be just `Branch`) i.e., the `(x:xs)` is taking up the (String, a), but even given that the code is wrong because (x:xs) isn't for a tuple but rather for lists, where x is the first element of the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part of the error that actually tells you what is happening is:

> ```
> Expected type: MyTree a -> a
>   Actual type: MyTree a -> [a]
> In the first argument of `map', namely `(list)'
> ```

So the type of the function you give to `map` is wrong. But why is it so? `map` has type:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

`list` is `MyTree a -> [a]`, and therefore:

```
map list :: (MyTree a -> [a]) -> [MyTree a] -> [[a]]
```

That means `map list xs` will have type `[[a]]`. You are using it like this:

```
list x ++ map list xs -- omitting unnecessary parentheses.
```

`(++)` is list concatenation; it expects two lists of the same type. `list x`, however, is `[a]` instead of `[[a]]`, which leads to the type error. Since `[a]` is the type of an element of `[[a]]`, you might try using `(:)`, instead of `(++)`, to prepend `list x` to the rest of your list-of-lists.

```
list (Branch _ (x:xs))        = list x : map list xs
```

That, however, is redundant: you are applying the same `list` function to `x` and the elements of `xs`. That means you can simplify it to:

```
list (Branch _ xs)        = map list xs
```

We are still not done, as `map list xs` has type `[[a]]`, and you want `[a]`. That is easy to solve, though: just use `concatMap`, which maps the function and flattens the resulting list-of-lists. The full definition would then become:

```
list :: MyTree a -> [a]
list (Leaf m)             = m
list (Branch _ xs)        = concatMap list xs
```

I have removed the redundant `(Leaf [])` case. Note that your function did not cover the `(
Branch _ [])` case; that's not a problem now that we are not matching `(x:xs)` only.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `map (list) xs` is `[[a]]` and you want something of type `[a]`. There is a function `concat` that we can use: `concat (map list xs)`, but we can write it more idiomatically with `concatMap`: `concatMap list xs`